# Why is an active Abstention/Pass Vote needed?

Tags: voting

Why can't we simply calculate everybody who don't vote, as an abstention/pass vote?

Comment: Nothing prevents you to change the voting rules!

Comment: But we need a discussion about it. It makes no sense to propose something without previous discussion. And as you can see from Lefessan's answer, there are definitely reasons why it is as it is.

Comment: i know i know :) i did not intend to suggest the contrary!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that there must be a significant participation of users to show that the vote is meaningful and that people are ok with the decision. For that, Tezos has a notion of quorum (80% today). If the participation is under the quorum, the vote is rejected (and the quorum is decreased).

This way, if you PASS, it means that you looked at the proposal, but don’t care if it is accepted or not. But you don’t prevent a majority of the voters from accepting it. You don’t change the quorum, so your vote will still be important for a next ballot. If you don’t vote, it doesn’t mean mean that you don’t care about the proposal, but that you are an inactive token holder, the quorum is updated so that the importance of your vote decreases over time.

Comment: I respect this idea but it It can also lead to slower evolution of the protocol.
If Tezos gets bigger my approach might be worth considering. People who are not interested (or don't care about the outcome) are more likely to do nothing than vote "pass".

Comment: Then, the quorum will decrease and only the part interested in the protocol will be taken into account. Unfortunately, it might be a very small part of the ecosystem, taking decisions for the vast majority.

Comment: A pass voting expresses exactly what you say; People do not care if others taking the decision. So i see no Problem in doing so. But let's wait and see how participation will be :)